# jQuery help - How do I select only the first item of a wrapped set?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css-selectors

How can I select the 1st item in a wrapped set? I have `$(":radio")`
This returns a wrapped set of two items. Is there any way I can select just the first item? Basically something like this but cleaner syntax

```
var singleListItem = $($(":radio")[0]);
```

That will probably work, but it looks hideous to me. Is there a better way to write this type of selector??

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
var singleListItem = $(":radio:first");
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first

Comment: much much cleaner. Thanks. I was looking in the index of "jQuery in Action", and there is no entry for "first". It was written for 1.3.1 so maybe it wasn't in there yet. i.e. "Closest".

Comment: Good, glad it was what you were looking for.

Comment: +1, I was mistaken $(":radio")[0] is the same as $(":radio").get(0). Don't know where I got the idea that they were different.